# How to use a variable in an AD filter string?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have following powershell script to get LDAP properties. I would like to pass the BadgeID as variable instead of hard coding it. The LDAP query is working with hard-coded BadgeID but it looks like if I replace the hard-coded value with a variable then it doesn't return anything.

```
$BadgeID = $item["BadgeID"]
$SearchBase = 'OU=Sales-Users,DC=mayoclinic,DC=com';
$LdapServer = 'MAYOCLNDC413.MAYOCLINIC.COM';

Get-ADUser -SearchBase $searchbase -SearchScope 'subtree' -Server $ldapserver -filter 'BadgeID -like "*74049660*"' -Properties * |
    Select -Property Name, AccountExpires, AccountExpirationDate, BadgeID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the quotes of your filter expression:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "BadgeID -like '*$BadgeID*'" ...
```

Variables are expanded in double-quoted strings, but not in single-quoted strings.